# implementing Notification System from MYSQL in C# Fails

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a database with this table which is used to store messages 
 and it looks like this

**Database : vms2 Table : vms_notification**

```
---------------------------------------------------------
|id  | user | sender   |   message         |     date    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|0   | gate| reception | hello i am tesing | 2017 -10-04 |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Now thats the table now i Created a class that is suppose to fetch the message from the database and pop up as a new Notification if the person at the gate logs into the system. Its a C# winform, so i wanted it to check the Email from the Mysql Server and make a MessageBox on the screen for the user to see once he has a new Mail.

My source code looks like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace VisitorManager2
{
    class Notification
    {
        public void NotifyMessenger()
        {
            string constring = "server=localhost;user id=root;database=vms2";
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constring))
            {
                string sql = "select * from vms2.vms_notification";
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    try
                    {
                        string userid = null;
                        string sender;
                        string message;
                        string date;

                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            userid = (rdr["user"].ToString());
                            sender = (rdr["sender"].ToString());
                            message = (rdr["message"].ToString());
                            date = (rdr["date"].ToString());
                        }

                        Loginform login = new Loginform();
                        string username = login.metroComboBox1.Text;

                        if (userid == username)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("New Notification!", "New Notification",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It just loads the Splashscreen, and once i log in, it loads the splashscreen again without even showing any notifications from the Email whatsoever. what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

You, first, run a query that selects all the rows from your table.

Second, you run a loop that retrieves all those rows and only saves the last one. The last one doesn't seem to match the user that logs in.

To fix this: Try fetching the user's login name first, then running a query of the form

```
   select * from vms2.vms_notification where user = 'username'
```

But do that using bind variables, something like this, to avoid the little Johnny Droptables problem (look it up).

```
con.Open();
...
string userid = null;
string sender;
string message;
string date;

const string sql = 
   "select * from vms2.vms_notification where user = @username;";

using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con))
{
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username); 
   var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   while (rdr.Read())
   {
      userid = (rdr["user"].ToString());
      sender = (rdr["sender"].ToString());
      message = (rdr["message"].ToString());
      date = (rdr["date"].ToString());
   }
}
```

This will fetch a row from your table relevant to the user who logged in. If that user has more than one row in the table, it will fetch only one of them.